# Python writing only the last element in dict to database

Tags: python, database, dictionary, dns, mx-record

I am getting the `mx-record` of the `domains` in the `database`. And then I write to the `rows` in the `relevant column`. However, the last value in `mx-record` written to `database`. What is the reason, how can I fix it?

My code:

```
domains = Domain.query.all()

for mx in domains:
    if mx:
        try:
            result = dns.resolver.resolve(mx.domain, 'MX')
            for mx_record in result:
                mx.mx_record = mx_record.to_text()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        finally:
            db.session.commit()
```

**the database output I want:**
My database table have to be like this.

| domain | mx_record |
| --- | --- |
| cat.com | 10 mail5.cat.com.,10 mail6.cat.com.,10 mail1.cat.com.,10 mail4.cat.com.,10 mail2.cat.com.,10 mail3.cat.com. |
| stackoverflow.com | 10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.,5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.,10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.,5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.,1 aspmx.l.google.com. |

Comment: I don't know what you expect but inside `for`-loop you assign to the same element and it removes previous values. If you want all values in the same row then you should first create one string from `for mx_record in result:`  and assign this single element. And if you need them in separated rows then in `for`-loop you should create new rows to assign new values (or duplicate existing row, add new value and save it).

Answer (score 0):

You run `for`-loop which assign all `mx_record.to_text()` to the same `mx` - and this removes previous values and you get only last one.

You should first create one string with all values and later assign single string. Something like this:

```py
result = dns.resolver.resolve(mx.domain, 'MX')

values = []
for mx_record in result:
    values.append(mx_record.to_text())

# values = [mx_record.to_text() for mx_record in result]  # shorter

one_string = ','.join(values)

mx.mx_record = one_string
```

Comment: I want only the mx-record information of that domain against the `domain` in the relevant column. However, when I make a `list`, it writes the `mx-record` of `all domains` in the `database` and `itself`.

Comment: you sould add expected result in question - not in my answer.  And first version would do what you expect. You have to convert all records to single string and assign this string

Comment: It is not a good idea to store a set (DNS replies are sets of records) as a single string. You will get all sorts of problems. You either have to normalize your tables properly, or use a type for the column that allows to write an array. But at this stage this is not really a question on DNS, more on DB design and use.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I agree with you. First OP didn't show expected result and I suggested also version which duplicate row and put evry `record` in new row but when I saw expected result then I removed this idea. But I was also thinking about separted table with rows `domain_ID, single_record` - but this would need more changes :)